# Looking to format column names to dates after reading in a CSV

Tags: r, for-loop, date-formatting, as.date

When I read in data from a CSV file, the column names return in this format:

```
X2017.04, X2017.05, X2017.06
```

I'm looking to format it as (or something similar to):

```
April-2017, May-2017, June-2017
```

Currently, I've tried for loops to iterate through the entire data set and reformat everything using `as.Date()` or `as.yearmon` and some of them have worked, *kinda*.

`as.yearmon` returned `1997.333333333` and similar looking floats. The `as.Date` code I tried returned blank values.

I'm relatively new/novice level in R and could use some help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `as.yearmon` you can try :

```
names(df) <- zoo::as.yearmon(names(df), 'X%Y.%m')
```

Or in base R pasting an arbitrary date :

```
names(df) <- format(as.Date(paste0(names(df), '.01'), 'X%Y.%m.%d'), '%b-%Y')
```

---

As an example :

```
x <- c('X2017.04', 'X2017.05', 'X2017.06')
format(as.Date(paste0(x, '.01'), 'X%Y.%m.%d'), '%b-%Y')
#[1] "Apr-2017" "May-2017" "Jun-2017"
```

Comment: Okay so the base R one worked in a for loop thank you! If you don't mind me asking, the '.01', what does that do in this particular argument? Everything else I understand. Is that setting the format of the data you're passing through?

Comment: In base R what we are trying to do is a create a date object. A date requires date, month and year. We already have month and year we add an arbitrary date 01 to it. We can then use `format` to get output in the format that we want.

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(lubridate)
format(ymd(sub('^X', "", x,), truncated = 2), '%b-%Y')
#[1] "Apr-2017" "May-2017" "Jun-2017"
```

#### data

```
x <- c('X2017.04', 'X2017.05', 'X2017.06')
```